# How to pass array of arguments in shell script?

Tags: shell, svn, unix, loops, cut

Right now i a have a working script to pass 2 arguments to a shell script. The script basically takes a ticket# and svn URL as arguments on command line and gives an output of all the revisions that have been changed associated with that ticket# (in svn comments).

```
#!/bin/sh

jira_ticket=$1
src_url=$2


revs=(`svn log $2 --stop-on-copy | grep -B 2 $1 | grep "^r" | cut -d"r" -f2 | cut -d" " -f1| sort`)

for revisions in ${!revs[*]}
    do
    printf "%s %s\n" ${revs[$revisions]}
done
```

Output:

```
4738
4739
4743
4744
4745
```

I need some help to pass an array of arguments - meaning more than one ticket# and give the output of revisions associated with those ticket numbers that get passed as args to the script.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think POSIX shell has arrays, so be plain and use `#!/bin/bash`

I would put the url as the first arg, and all the reset are tickets

```
#!/bin/bash
revs=()
src_url=$1
svn_log=$(svn log "$src_url" --stop-on-copy)
shift
for jira_ticket in "$@"; do   
    revs+=( $(grep -B 2 "$jira_ticket" <<< "$svn_log" | grep "^r" | cut -d"r" -f2 | cut -d" " -f1) )
done
for revisions in $( printf "%s\n" "${!revs[@]}" | sort )
    do
    printf "%s %s\n" ${revs[$revisions]}
done
```

Comment: 1/ What is $1 and $2 here ? 2/ What if there is 3rd arg to be passed like $target_url ?

Comment: @iaav, I updated by answer a bit to correct my errors from pasting your code. It should be more clear. Also, it only calls `svn log` once, so optimized a bit.

Comment: I suspect I have not answered your real question: please post the output of `svn log`

Comment: is this the usage? `./script.sh $src_url ticket-1 ticket-2 ticket-3 ?`

Comment: yes exactly. Once the src_url is assigned and the first parameter is `shift`ed, all the remaining parameters (`"$@"`) are tickets

Comment: I gave this at command line: `./script.sh $src_url $target_url ticket-1 ticket-2 ticket-3` and it ignore $target_url and took the tickets as $@. I thought it would take all the parameters after $src_url.